# Cannot convert project: C:\workspace_IntelliJ\Main\new-webapp\.idea\workspace.xml: Error on line 1: Content is not allowed in prolog

Tags: java, xml, intellij-idea, ide

I have no clue what suddenly have happened. I restarted my Idea workspace and it popped up the following error:

> Cannot convert project: C:\workspace_IntelliJ\Main\new-webapp.idea\workspace.xml: Error on line 1: Content is not allowed in prolog.

What does this error mean? I have checked my workspace.xml. Whenever I try to open it in an editor it displays the following (I believe it's broken):

```
nulnulnul
```

I have no clue what to change and how to fix this thing. Any help on this would be great!

Comment: workspace.xml is not a well-formed document. "nulnulnul", if that's what's there, is certainly wrong. Discard it and create a new workspace... and figure out how you damaged this one so you don't do it again.

Comment: Thanks, Keshlam, I figured that out before you posted, and yes it started to work :) but do you know why it happened just curious?

Comment: Not a toolset I use, so I can't offer any other thoughts. I'm just responding to the parser's complaint that what you gave it wasn't proper XML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I fixed the problem (not sure yet why the file got broken though). 
Step1: I created a new workspace and copied my source files and `.idea` files excluding workspace.xml. Infact I deleted it before copying it to new workspace.

It worked! guess deleting and re-creating was the option

Answer (score 5):

Just remove workspace.xml file. It worked for me ;)

Comment: My colleague accidently turned off my computer and this solves my problem. thanks.

Comment: Similar happened to me. I just updated IntelliJ from 15.0.2 to 15.0.3. My PC shut down due to idle time and when I reopened IntelliJ, all of my settings were gone and this issue with the workspace.xml happened. Deleting the file worked for me. IntelliJ will regenerate the file on next successful build.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this problem can be fixed by opening up the .idea/workspace.xml file in a text editor and saving it specifically with UTF-8 encoding.  This is possible using Sublime Text for example.  This fixed the problem for me.